# different result about bitwise operator in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

in order to realize logical right shift in c , i search the web and got the following C code

```
int a, b, c;
int x = -100;
a = (unsigned) x >> 2;
b = (0xffffffff & x) >> 2;
c = (0x0 | x ) >> 2;
```

now both a and b were logical right shift result(1006632960), but c was still arithmetic shift result(-25)， could somebody explain why ? thx

Answer (score 1):

```
b = (0xffffffff & x) >> 2;
```

Assuming that your ints are 32 bits, the type of the literal constant `0xffffffff` is `unsigned int`, because it is too large to fit in a plain `int`. The `&`, then, is between an `unsigned int` and an `int`, in which case the unsigned type wins by definition. The shift therefore happens on unsigned; thus it shifts in 0 bits from the left.

```
c = (0x0 | x ) >> 2;
```

The type of `0x0` defaults to `int` because it is small enough to fit, so the bitwise or happens on ints, and so does the following shift. It is implementation defined what happens when you shift a signed integer right, but most compilers will produce an arithmetic shift that sign-extends.

Comment: any documents support this point about seeing literal constant as unsigned int when large and signed when small?

Comment: Section 6.4.4.1, subsection 5, of the C99 standard? "The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented." The list for decimal constants contains only nsigned types, but octal and hex constants can also be unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

`(unsigned) x` is of type unsigned int so it get a logical shift.

`0xffffffff` (assuming 32 bit int) is of type unsigned int, so `(0xffffffff & x)` is also of type unsigned int so it get a logical shift.

`0x0` is of type int, so `(0x0|x)` is of type int and get an arithmetic shift (well, it is implementation dependent).

Comment: what confused me is that why C compiler treats 0xffffffff and 0x0 differently, are they not both numeric constant?

Comment: yes, but of different type. The type of an hexadecimal constant without suffix is the first of `int`, `unsigned`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, `unsigned long long` able to represent the *value*. 0x0 is representable in an int, 0xffffffff isn't (at least for a 32 bit int, it is a value of 2^32-1, not a bit pattern)

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the operand type of the `operator >>`. If it's `signed` - the right-shift sets the MSB to 1 if the operand was negative. If the operand is `unsigned` - MSB bits are always zero after right-shift.

In your first expression the operand is cast explicitly to `unsigned`.

In the second expression the `(0xffffffff & x)` us unsigned, because `0xffffffff` definitely represents an unsigned integer (it's an overflow for `signed`).

OTOH in the third example `0x0` is `signed` (this is the default for integer constants). Hence the whole operand `(0x0 | x )` is considered signed